# Keep leading zero when inserting a string into a SELECT (MySql)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Here is my string (that is string NOT int):

```
string code = "0101";
```

Here is my SQL:

```
string select = "SELECT " + code + " AS code" ...
```

Here is what I get in the table:

```
code
101
101
101    
...
```

Here is what I need:

```
code
0101
0101
...
```

P.S. Tried both `CAST` and `CONVERT`.

Comment: If only there were some way to indicate which dialect of SQL a question referred to. It's almost as some sort of tagging mechanism might be handy. Perhaps we should raise a change request on SO to get them to add it :-)

Comment: You need to tell us what flavour of SQL you are using. The answer will vary between them.

Comment: If only I knew enough to understand that there is more than one dialect of SQL :). Will fix it now :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`0101` is a numeric literal, and when displaying numbers leading zeros are removed. You could treat it as a string literal by surrounding it with single quotes (`'`):

```
string code = "0101";
string select = "SELECT '" + code + "' AS code" ...
```